# How to increase the number of folders in VsCode right click?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have to work with a lot of VsCode folder. So I need to quickly access different folders. So I would like to increase my number of folders in my right-click window but I can't do it.

I tried to increase this:

"workbench.editor.limit.value": 10 to
"workbench.editor.limit.value": 20

But that didn't change anything.
I tried other manipulations but I can't find this command. Does anyone have an idea for me to increase my number of folders?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has little to do with VS Code and instead to do with your OS, but I'm not 100% sure...